How can I connect mysql to openai-api?
I connected the OpenAI API key to my SpringBoot project and I would like to know how I can connect it to my data on MySql. OpenAI tells me that by guaranteeing him a user with all privileges on mysql he can then access but I don't know how to pass this created user to him. Apart from this way, would there be another perhaps safer way to have it read from my data?
I tried to pass it the result of a query as input and asked it to search in that array, but the result is not the one hoped for and it doesn't always return the expected one, it manages to work with the ids but not with the other fields.
Many thanks in advance.
